# Conditional formatting choice fields

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form I would like to create where the choice fields are grayed out either after a certain date or when the choice is temporarily no longer available.

Example: we have four publications a year. After the magazine is published, we don't want the choice to be selected (or at least to gray it out), but still want it to show, so users would know it is available for next year. I haven't found any way to do this so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

At the moment we do not have a way to disable Choice field options. This is a feature that is on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/fDuf8Qku). You can follow our progress, and vote for this feature, and other features that you would like to see us work on for future Cognito Forms releases.